# Feature Scaling + Selection when target is imbalanced

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, class-imbalance, feature-scaling

If my target is imbalanced, when should I do target balancing in preparation for modeling?

Before feature scaling and selection? After feature scaling and selection?
If I am doing backward elimination, would the p values not be affected if my target is imbalanced?

Also, should I scale my features before doing feature selection?

Thank you for helping me during the confusion.

Comment: Statisticians do not see class imbalance as a problem, and there is no need to use undersampling, oversampling, or artificial balancing to solve a non-problem. It might be helpful if you say why you find the imbalance problematic. 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466
https://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage/
https://www.fharrell.com/post/classification/ 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/359936/247274 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/464636/
https://twitter.com/f2harrell/status/1062424969366462473?lang=en